Timestamp in database is European (16:35), but in CakePHP application is UTC (14:35)
Working on development of application, using CakePHP 5 framework.
Problem I have, is that it shows different timestamp for same record in application and in database.
To prevent that, I made changes in bootstrap.php file, I changed line with default timezone to:
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Bratislava');

In database is stored also with timespamp 16:35.
But if I read that data in application, from database, it shows 14:35.
Can you help me please how to get same time (in this case 16:35) in my application, also?
Thank you in advance!

In my config/app.php, I have:
'App' => [
    'timezone' => [
        'name' => $timezone,
    ],
],

and also
'Datasources' => [
    'default' => [
        ...
        'timezone' => $timezone,

Then in my config/bootstrap.php, I have
date_default_timezone_set(Configure::read('App.timezone.name'));
Together, these set me up for correct time zone handling everywhere.
